How can I purify the RNA from polyribosomes on microtubules in mammalian cells?
I've found some old papers that used triton-x-100 to fractionate cells and obtain the cytoskeleton fraction which includes polyribosomes. I'm assuming this is still the best method for isolating microtubules and associated RNA?
Does anyone know a good method/protocol for purifying the mRNAs associated with microtubules from cells? Would really appreciate tips for a simple way of doing this

I am not sure if this is the best way, but if you have a defined fraction which contains your RNA of interest, I would probably simply do a Phenol/Chloroform extraction.
